# Can Nautilus display a .desktop file by its real name?

Tags: nautilus, files

The ability of a .desktop file to display a "human-readable" alias rather than its (perhaps) clinical **real** name, has merit... and as the *.desktop* filetype suggests, I assume that this ability is intended for the **Desktop** (which is (co-?)managed by Nautilus).

However in the Nautilus File Manager itself, where I would expect to see the bare-bones file information (eg. the real name), I am presented with the meta-data *alias* instead of the *real* filename.

This makes it rather difficult to edit/view the *.desktop* file when Nautilus does not make the real name available.

Is there some way to have Nautilus GUI **File Manager** list these .desktop files by their real names?  (just like *ls*)

PS.. These files had me completely puzzled until today, when I renamed one, and the (my) new "name" was actually *not* the new real filename at all!. The displayed name was an alias; Nautilus had modified the **file's contents** (Name=...), and the original name was unchanged! ... now I am only half-puzzled (strange stuff)

Comment: Sounds Like a challenge for a nautilus script! maybe a mod of filetype script?

Comment: ...actually, the more I think about it, the stranger it seems. When a standard "rename" feature actually **modifies a file's contents**, that's going beyond the call of duty, as far as I'm concerned... Well, at least that's not what I expect of a File **Manager**... I thought that was what File Editors (and Property Sheets) were for... and yes, a Nautilus script will allow me to edit/view the file... But I still wonder what is so "special" about .desktop files that Nautilus gives them such "special" treatment.. treatment which is quite non-standard for file "Manager".

Comment: I cant really see why it wouldn't be possible to rename it to the package it relates to as by default packages should have a unique name. With maybe an Identifier for multiple entries Prism Launcher for instance. Can't check an example at the mo been confined to a Windows vista Box....... (cries in to Coffee)

Comment: What version of nautilus are you using?

Comment: @DoR. You've spotted the problem "just like that!"... I'm using Nautilus 2.30.1 (Lucid 10.04)... I've just now tried Nautilus 2.32.0 in a VM version of 10.10, and it works; the new name does now appear in the `ls` listing...  I had tried Maverick in a VM within a fortnight of it being released, but it crashed a couple of times, and being very new to Linux/Ubuntu, I decided to hold off until I'd learnt enough to be able to deal with a potential install drama..  This has been a "sign!"..I may be switching sooner than I expected ...and now, all I need is an **answer** so I can mark it "solved" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With newer versions of Nautilus ([2.31.5](http://mail.gnome.org/archives/ftp-release-list/2010-July/msg00018.html) and later) renaming `.desktop` files actually changes the filename, not the `Name` field of the file itself.

Nautilus  will show the full filename (with the `.desktop` extension), if the `.desktop` file is **not** executable.

For example,
if `Firefox.desktop` is executable:

[image]

Now to see the actual filename, make `Firefox.desktop` un-executable. *Right click -> Properties -> Permissions -> Uncheck  `Allow executing file as a program`.*

[image]
Now Nautilus will show the full file name:

[image]

> [image] There seems to be a bug with renaming un-executable `.desktop` files in Nautilus.
>   If you don't erase the `.desktop` extension, the file will
>   have a double-extension (i.e `Firefox.desktop.desktop`).

Comment: Thanks DoR... In amongst the side issues, I somehow lost sight of my original question ... ie. Can Nautilus show the "real filename"?  ...I think it is clear now... Nautilus does what it does!... and that is: It *always* shows the alias name... Now that I know this, whenever I want the *real* filename, I can use a Nautilus Script... (It seems that using `ls` will be a "best-guess" method, because the *real* name may be significantly different).

Comment: @fred.bear Edited my answer ;)

Comment: Yes! .. I was getting that double .desktop!  ...quite puzzling..  (and another gremlin, but there's no point going into it... in normal usage it works fine.. and I now know what to expect :)

Comment: quote: "Nautilus will show the full filename, if the .desktop file is not executable." This behaviour is so unbelievable! The first request I have from a file manager is to SHOW me the name of a file, not some other information, WHATEVER the type of of the file is.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from nautilus' strangeness, here's a nautilus script.

You can select multiple files, click ok and gedit will show them (requires zenity).

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=$(ls -1 | zenity --list --hide-header --multiple --separator "\n" --title "List directory contents" --width 400 --height 300 --column "ls")
IFS="
"
test -z "$FILE" || gedit $FILE
```

Put it in `~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts` and make it executable.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion... I have previously used Nautilus Actions, but you've propted me to take a look a Nautilus Scripts, and I like it! ... and I also like the dialog interface of `zenity`

Answer (score 0):

We can display the real file names in Nautilus without making use of additional scripts.

Nautilus will display the alias of a `.desktop`-file for `.desktop`-files which are located in `/usr/share` and `/usr/local/share` including all sub-directories of both directories. Nautilus will display the real file-name if the `.desktop`-file is located anywhere else.

We can do a simple trick with a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /usr /USR
```

If we browse in Nautilus to `/usr/share/applications`, Nautilus will display the aliases for the `.desktop`-files.

If we browse in Nautilus to `/USR/share/applications`, Nautilus will display the real file-names of the `.desktop`-files.

Try it, I tested this on several Ubuntu-flavours with the versions 16.04 and 17.04. This also works in Xubuntu, Thunar has the same behavior as Nautilus.