# Appearance of a .desktop file in Nautilus

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, .desktop

This is Ubuntu 14.04. Nautilus version 3.10.1.

I have a "file.desktop" file in my  personal "~/bin/shortcuts" directory.

When I look at the directory with Nautilus, 
it shows the "Name=" field value from the desktop file as the file name rather than the real "file.desktop" name. This is true for both List and Icons view modes.

The files having executable bit cleared or set does not change anything.

However, it shows the real *.desktop names for the files at the standard locations: `~/.local/share/applications`

Another effect: When Ctrl+(drag-drop) these files are not copied. However, Alt+(drag-drop)=>Copy does the copy, and the new file name is named "file (copy).desktop", while Nautilus now shows two identical entries with the same "Name=" field. Confusing...

Anyone has a rationale for this, and **how** can I turn these effects off? I'd prefer to see the real file names for all files.

Comment: I think showing the content of the `Name=` field is the usual behavour of nautilus.

Comment: @LittleByBlue But then how come at ~/.local/share/applications it does show the real file names anyway?

Comment: That is because they miss the icon. There is a `Icon=` field, but there is no icon image. so they show up as a textfile.

Comment: to show the `*.desktop` name you may need to remove the icon image.

Comment: @LittleByBlue Removing or presence of the `Icon=` field and valid value does not make a difference, other than the icon next to the entry in Nautilus.

Comment: Ah got it: if you add the `Type=Application` field it will show up as a textfile.

Comment: @LittleByBlue again, removing Type=Application has no effect. Same .desktop file contents has different behavior depending on location: for example, my shortcuts directory and at `~/.local/share/application`.

Comment: All I can say is that the following is the *normal* behaviour: executable `.desktop` file => icon shows, shown name is `Name=` line; *not* executable `.desktop` file: name = real file name, icon does not show. Maybe you need to update desktop? (F5). PS why keep `.desktop` filoes in a `~/bin` directory?

Comment: @LittleByBlue the icon and the name as in the `Name=` line only show up on an *executable* `.desktop` file.

Comment: @JacobVlijm: why ~/bin/shortcuts? I like to keep my custom shortcuts separately (as opposed to the mess generated by the installation) and then symlinking them to the standard location. Thus I can also backup and auto-share my custom shortcuts among several machines (e.g. using Dropbox or svn). Why custom shortcuts a all? For example: I like to view/edit photos with Irfanview via Wine. Another - I have a shell script that does custom tasks depending on file extension. I need .desktop files to be able to associate files by extension with this script (in Nautilus and GDM).

Comment: There is some insight in this question/answer: "Can Nautilus display a .desktop file by its real name?" -  http://askubuntu.com/questions/17220/can-nautilus-display-a-desktop-file-by-its-real-name?rq=1

Comment: The rule on when a .desktop file shows its "real" name is straightforward (see my comment) but why keeping .desktop files on a location for executables (or links to executables)? That is not an appropriate location for a .desktop file.

Answer (score 0):

It must be specific `nautilus` behaviour (read: Bug/Feature) as `nemo` (a fork of Nautilus) shows the Name= regardless of the location of the file (as would be expected)

This was tested in `~/.local/share/applications` and `/usr/share/application` on Nemo.

Comment: Well, maybe for nemo, but for Nautilus - not "regardless of the location" according to my observations. Thanks for the answer, but I am looking for a better one. For one, this apparently is a bug/feature, but this does not give me a solution to the stated problem.

Comment: So? Did you ever find an adequate solution? @elomage (Someone just upvoted, so I suppose they moved over to nemo)