# How do you get a *.desktop file to work for a non-repository app?

Tags: files, icons, .desktop, syntax, location

I turned the Amazon cloud reader site https://read.amazon.com into a desktop app with `nativefier`. It works amazingly well as a standalone reader for books that have been downloaded and also automatically downloads books in the cloud when requested.

Instead of launching `/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web` from the console all the time, I tried to make a Kindle-Web desktop file to place in the launcher. My file won't work in two ways:

1. It won't launch Kindle-Web.
2. It does not display the Kindle icon on the file when viewed in Nautilus.

The code is below. Can anyone tell me where I went wrong. The icon files are in `/home/myname/.local/share/icons/hicolor/<resolution-folders>`, and `/home/myname/.icons/hicolor/*`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Kindle-Web
Comment=Desktop app created from Kindle Cloud Reader page (https://read.amazon.com) by nativefier
Exec=/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web
Path=/home/myname/
# StartupNotify=true
# StartupWMClass=kindle-web
Icon=0914_Kindle.0
# Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Publishing;Literature;Documentation;Office;
```

Comment: Is the .desktop file executable?

Comment: The icon path is also incorrect. If .desktop is executable too, then what do you get when you double click on .desktop file?

Comment: @Kulfy The icon path is most probably not as issue provided there is actually an image file named `0914_Kindle.0` in one of the `hicolor` directories. hicolor *is* the default fallback theme for icon themes (if the icon is not found in the current icon theme, it should look into hicolor for icons).

Comment: So does running `/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web` in Terminal launch the application?

Comment: @pomsky But I believe this is the reason why *It does not display the Kindle icon on the file when viewed in Nautilus.*

Comment: @Kulfy Wrong icon specification can be a reason, but not sure if that's the reason here. File managers don't generally show the specified icon for .desktop launchers unless they're executable (see [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1098317/480481) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/17220/480481) for example). OP hasn't clarified if it's executable.

Comment: @pomsky Yeah I agree with your point.

Comment: @Xen2050, @pomsky, @Kulfy The `Kindle.desktop` file is executable. It is temporarily in the `~/Desktop` folder. When you double-click it, a *There was an error launching the application* alert appears. @pomsky Running `/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web` in the console does launch the Kindle Cloud Reader as a desktop app. @Kulfy Quoting you, *"there is actually an image file named `0914_Kindle.0` in one of the hicolor directories."*

Answer (score 0):

If running

```
/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web
```

in Terminal indeed launches the application whereas the `.desktop` launcher doesn't, then change the `Exec` line from

```
Exec=/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web
```

to

```
Exec=bash -c '/home/myname/kindle-web-linux-x64/kindle-web'
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome actually has a feature to make a shortcut on desktop, which on Linux will effectively create a `.desktop` shortcut.

Steps to create:

1. Open `https://read.amazon.com` in Google Chrome
2. Click on the Chrome's top right menu
3. Navigate to <kbd>More tools</kbd> →  <kbd>Create a shortcut</kbd>

At this point you should have the `.desktop` file in your home directory, which should launch a single chrome window. You can customize the resulting file if you like.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer about my experience.

1. First I recommend, not using "." on icon names. I am not sure why, but I had in past the same problem with a desktop file with an icon called with org.xxx.xxx style, and icon never shown in "Application Menu".
2. I recommend that your icon have at least 128x128 version.
3. Call the update-icon-caches

```bsh
update-icon-caches ~/.local/share/icons
```

4. Copy your desktop file to ~/.local/share/applications and run the update-desktop-database

```bsh
update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
```

So now, you should see the app in "Applications Menu" with correct icon displayed